# How to use media query for max-width: 767px using Bootstrap 4 mobile first

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I am converting a website that I made from scratch to be responsive using Bootstrap 4. I started the conversion before I realized that Bootstrap 4 is mobile first, my site was developed desktop first. Without going back and re-doing the entire site, I thought I could just add a few changes with this media query:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        /***HOMEPAGE - HEADER***/
        #header {
            height: 45vh;
            background-attachment: inherit;
        }
    }
```

The changes are not shown on the site but I can see the code when I inspect element and click on sources. My other queries are working just fine, they look like this:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        /***BODY ***/
        html,
        body,
        a,
        blockquote {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        /***MAIN & MOBILE NAV***/
        .main-nav {
            display: none;
        }

        #nav-icon3 {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

I tried adding this meta tag:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    maximum-scale=1">
```

That made everything look jumbled beneath 767px.

I just need to make a few minor tweaks for when the screen is less than 767px and I do not want to re-build my site from mobile first, nor do I want to convert to Bootstrap 3 at this point. Please Help!

Comment: are you using sass or only css?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to find out if this gets overwritten by another rule with higher specificity somewhere.

Comment: @CBroe it doesn't show up in the dev tools at all, so I don't think it's being overwritten. It seems like it's being ignored because I can see it in the CSS file when I click on sources.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy just CSS

Answer (score 5):

If you are using safari browser use viewport as
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">`

[Safari Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW36)

and another reference [why shrink-to-fit=no](http://kihlstrom.com/2015/shrink-to-fit-no-fixes-zoom-problem-in-ios-9/)

As per [Bootstrap 4 documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) Responsive breakpoints are

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

other direction

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops)
// No media query since the extra-large breakpoint has no upper bound on its width
```

and minimum and maximum breakpoint widths

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: Not using Safari... I am using the one mentioned in the second box, showing the other direction queries: // Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... } It is just not showing up at all in the web dev tools, only showing up under sources.

Comment: Do you prefer min and max breakpoints or min-width only (as in mobile up)?

Comment: Meta tag for viewport was the solution for my problems. Upvoted. What happened before I added this meta tag was that on mobile (or quazi mobile in inspector tool) CSS with media query for `min-width: 768px` was applied despite device width being 320px or 375px. Thanks.